vscode image/folder not displaying regardless of followings
i tried followings but file/folder image still not showing.
i've installed python extension, pylance and python debugger
But the code for python yet works.
I appreciate yout help,
Thanks,
What else do i have to try to solve file/image showing?
file associations item and value 
 edit in json 

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
